# How to call redis.evalsha

Tags: ruby, redis

I faced a doubt on how to use r.evalsha under ruby. I able to get result on CLI to call redis. Error shown me: **attempt to concatenate local 'nid' (a boolean value)**

Please advise me .

Thank You.

```
evalsha 0ca2da3beea9739f3d61798a36bd4d5ed56754ee 1 10.17.103.200
```

The testredis.rb like at following:

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'redis' 
r = Redis.new(:host => '127.0.0.1', :port => '6379' ) 
$result = r.evalsha("0ca2da3beea9739f3d61798a36bd4d5ed56754ee", ['1'],    ['10.17.103.200'])
puts $result
r.quit()
```

Comment: @for_stack, i had tested my lua script manually under CLI. No pro for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ruby redis gem attempts to clean up some things for you. You don't need to pass the number of arguments. The second argument to `evalsha` is an array of script arguments. Your `evalsha` line should look like this:

```
$result = r.evalsha("0ca2da3beea9739f3d61798a36bd4d5ed56754ee", ['10.17.103.200'])
```

To load a script from within ruby you can use `Redis#script`:

```
sha = r.script(:load, "return redis.call('incr', 'foo')")
r.evalsha(sha) # => 1
r.evalsha(sha) # => 2
```